# Basics > Runtime > Core primitives > frame_system / node_primitives vs core primitives / Docu of a Pallet configuration trait

Tags: pallet, traits, coreprimitives, node-primitives, frame-system

My questions relate to Core Primitives for setting up a node with FRAME.

1. Do I include the Core Primitives by using the Crate **frame_system** or Crate **node_primitives**?
2. The core primitives mentioned here: https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/runtime/#core-primitives are different from the types listed here: https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/node_primitives/all.html
   How does this difference come about?
3. If I want to add the pallet_timestamp to my runtime, where do I see the needed primitive data types? All documentation I have found call a similar comment such as:
   ' Import the Timestamp pallet ... and derive the pallet configuration trait from the timestamp trait.' Where do I find the documentation of the trait?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

BR
Cindy

Comment: Hi Cindita, what specifically are you trying to do? The core primitives mentioned in the documentation are not things you need to import manually. They are all included automatically in the `frame_system` pallet. As for adding the timestamp pallet, just look at: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L230

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi: Thank you very much. This is exactly the answer I needed. It is included in frame_system. I did not find such a clear answer in any documentation. Will check the github Link for the timestamp pallet. Great!

Answer (score 2):

The node 'client' runs the runtime (which has all the pallets in it).
The node_primitives are defined for the client rather than for the runtime. For pallets one would want to refer to frame_system rather than things on the host node.

For `pallet_timestamp` have a look at how other parachains have used it as an example. Here Acala is configuring it: https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/9b1a7b7aa84b98621bddc7efdc0b3a6875cdb380/runtime/karura/src/lib.rs#L345

Comment: Thank you very much @Squirrel. Still not clear to me: 1. How do I include the core primitives ? Is it with frame_system? 2. Is there a general documentation available for each Pallet regarding its trait configuration (without a reference to a special project as Acala)?

Comment: Each pallet should have documentation for it generated via rustdoc. Please do suggest PRs to improve the pallet docs and point out bits that are unclear and we can improve them in the PR.